# Creating two textfields with only bottom border swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create two UITextFields that both only have the bottom border, I got some code from another StackOverflow and it worked. However, when I copy and pasted the code again for my second TextField it only shows one TextField with the bottom border.

Here is the code:

```
 let border = CALayer()
 let width = CGFloat(2.0)
 border.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
 border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: emailText.frame.size.height - 
width, width:  emailText.frame.size.width, height: 
emailText.frame.size.height)

border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: passwordText.frame.size.height 
- width, width:  passwordText.frame.size.width, height: 
passwordText.frame.size.height)

    border.borderWidth = width
    passwordText.layer.addSublayer(border)
    passwordText.layer.masksToBounds = true

    border.borderWidth = width
    emailText.layer.addSublayer(border)
    emailText.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you cant use the same vie for both textfield. Use a copy of  border for the second one.  Easiest way to make this work is to refine a variable as border2 and set it up and sublayer it.

Comment: Your issue is *likely* that you've only created one *instance* of `border`, and it cannot be added to two `UITextFields. You have a few options - (1) create a second instance of `border`, subclass `UITextField` and have the subclass have a bottom border. It may be "cleaner" (or more OOP) to subclass, but if you are not looking to reuse this kind of textfield except in the two instances, it's easier to create two instances - but name them `pwBorder` and `emailBorder` for clarity.

Comment: @CalvinChange its becuase your assigning the border frame and then again you are assign it and so it get override with new frame size .

Comment: @Gihan it worked thanks

Answer (score 1):

`CALayer`s are instance-based, that means if you added the layer to a view, you cannot add it to a new one without removing it from the first view. Create two instances of `CALayer`s or better yet, make an extension that produces the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Create separate border object for email textfield and username textfield.

```
let emailborder = CALayer()
let passwordborder = CALayer()

let width = CGFloat(2.0)
emailborder.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
emailborder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: emailText.frame.size.height - 
width, width:  emailText.frame.size.width, height: 
emailText.frame.size.height)

passwordborder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: passwordText.frame.size.height 
- width, width:  passwordText.frame.size.width, height: 
passwordText.frame.size.height)

passwordborder.borderWidth = width
passwordText.layer.addSublayer(passwordborder)
passwordText.layer.masksToBounds = true

emailborder.borderWidth = width
emailText.layer.addSublayer(emailborder)
emailText.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use the same view for both textfield. Use a copy of border for the second one. Easiest way to make this work is to refine a variable as border2 and set it up and sublayer it. Don't forget to remove your duplicate frame assign for boarder.

```
let border = CALayer()  
let width = CGFloat(2.0)  
border.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor  
border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: emailText.frame.size.height -  width, width:  emailText.frame.size.width, height:  emailText.frame.size.height)

let border2 = CALayer() border2.borderColor = border.borderColor border2.frame = border.frame;

border.borderWidth = width
passwordText.layer.addSublayer(border)
passwordText.layer.masksToBounds = true

border.borderWidth = width
emailText.layer.addSublayer(border2)
emailText.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

The best you could without writing redundant code is that you create a function, pass the textfields you want to border as parameters and keep the styling code in there like so:

```
func setBorder(tf: UITextField) {

    let border = CALayer()
    let width = CGFloat(2.0)

    border.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: tf.frame.size.height - width, 
    width:  tf.frame.size.width, height: 
    tf.frame.size.height)
    border.borderWidth = width

    tf.layer.addSublayer(border)
    tf.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Call this function in viewDidLoad:

```
setBorder(tf: emailText)
setBorder(tf: passwordText)
```

Hope this helps!